# My Samsung Galaxy J6 phone can't connect to my laptop (ubuntu 20.04) Wi-Fi hotspot (Ethernet connected)

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, samsung, hot-spot

I'm using ethernet connection on my ASUS Aspire 3 laptop. Recently I've updated to 20.04 (when I was using 18.04 i didn't have such problems). My phone can see the network but when trying to connect it blocks and just can't connect. My friend does connect using iPhone, so it's not about laptop. Also my phone can connect to any other Wi-Fi network beside this one, so it's not about phone either. I've done the factory data reset and that didn't help. Tried changing band to 5 ghz as well as 2.4.

Comment: You say your friend can connect to the network with his phone.  You acknowledge that it's not an issue with the laptop.  I don't see how we can advise you on this problem if it's isolated to your phone

Answer (score 2):

I also had this same situation. Galaxy J6 unable to connect to hotspot while other phones could connect easily. As a quick workaround, try to change network's security type to either NONE or WEP (it worked for me).
This issue arises with WPA/WPA2-PSK security type (which is default) is used with this phone.